# Can't seem to use left or right shift

Tags: c++, bit-shift, bitset

I was just playing around a bit(no pun intended) with `std::bitset` in c++ and I ran in to a problem.

I can use `OR`, `AND` and `EXCLUSIVE OR` just fine, but when I try to do shift operations using `>>` and `<<` I get an error saying

> Error: no operator "<<" matches these operands

The code I have looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bitset<8> test = 0x05;
    bitset<8> test2 = 0x00;
    bitset<8> lshift = test << test2;
    cout<<lshift<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't have more code? 'Cause I don't see `>>` in your code

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's supposed to say << in the error. I will edit it

Comment: Presumably you wanted `test << test2.to_ulong();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is simply no such operator defined for shifting a `std::bitset` by another `std::bitset`. The only shifting operators are defined for arguments of type `std::size_t`, see for example http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_ltltgtgt.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I just assumed that you could use a bitset to shift another bitset

Answer (score 2):

You can always write the operator yourself if you really want it. Preferably templated though :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

bitset<8> operator<<(bitset<8>& rhs, bitset<8>& lhs) {
    return rhs << (std::size_t)lhs.to_ulong();
}

int main()
{
    bitset<8> test = 0x01;
    bitset<8> test2 = 0x01;
    bitset<8> lshift = test << test2;
    cout << lshift << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This operator is not defined for the bitset
However the class has the following member operator

```
bitset<N> operator<<(size_t pos) const noexcept;
```

So all you need that the shift would work is to replace `test2` for `test2.to_ulong()`

```
bitset<8> lshift = test << test2.to_ulong();
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

const size_t N = 8;

int main()
{
    std::bitset<N> test  = 0x05;
    std::bitset<N> test2 = 0x01;
    std::bitset<N> lshift = test << test2.to_ulong();

    std::cout << lshift << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
00001010
```